# easy regex is confusing

Tags: regex, r

I can't seem to get the email address from the following phrase:

> "mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?"

So far I've tried

```
regexpr(":([^\\?*]?)", phrase)
```

The logic of the code is as follows:

1. start with the semicolon character :
2. get every character that is not a question mark
3. return those characters inside the parenthesis.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong in my regex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us have a look at your regex and we'll see where you're going wrong. We'll pull it apart to make it easier to talk about:

```
:            Just a literal colon, no worries here.
(            Open a capture group.
    [        Open a character class, this will match one character.
        ^    The leading ^ means "negate this class"
        \\   This ends up as a single \ when the regex engine sees it and that will
             escape the next character.
        ?    This has no special meaning inside a character class, sometimes a
             question mark is just a question mark and this is one of those
             times. Escaping a simple character doesn't do anything interesting.
        *    Again, we're in a character class so * has no special meaning.
    ]        Close the character class.
    ?        Zero or one of the preceding pattern.
)            Close the capture group.
```

Stripping out the noise gives us `:([^?*]?)`.

So your regex actually matches:

> A colon followed by zero or one characters that aren't question marks or asterisks and that non-question-mark or non-asterisk will be in the first capture group.

That's nothing like what you're trying to do. A couple adjustments should sort you out:

```
:([^?]*)
```

That matches:

> A colon followed by any number of non-question-marks and the non-question-marks will be in the first capture group.

The `*` outside the character class is special, outside the character class it means "zero or more", inside the character class it is just an `*`.

I'll leave it to someone else to help you with the R side of things, I just want you to understand what's going on with the regex.

Comment: Thanks for breaking things down. I realized where my mistakes were and what I was actually suppose to do. That was really helpful.

Comment: @user1103294: Thanks, I like to think of myself as a [fishing instructor](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/2279.html) :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty straightforward approach with `gsub`:

```
gsub("([a-z]+:)(.*)([?]$)", "\\2", "mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?")
## Or, if you expect things other than characters before the colon
gsub("(.*:)(.*)([?]$)", "\\2", "mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?")
## Or, discarding the first and third groups since they aren't very useful
gsub(".*:(.*)[?]$", "\\1", "mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?")
```

Building off of where @TylerRinker started, you can also use `strsplit` as follows (to avoid having to then `gsub` out the question mark):

```
strsplit("mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?", ":|\\?", fixed=FALSE)[[1]][2]
```

How about if you had a list of such strings?

```
phrase <- c("mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?", 
            "mailto:somefunk.y-address@Sqmpalm.net?")
phrase
# [1] "mailto:fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com?"  
# [2] "mailto:somefunk.y-address@Sqmpalm.net?"

## Using gsub
gsub("(.*:)(.*)([?]$)", "\\2", phrase)
# [1] "fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com"     "somefunk.y-address@Sqmpalm.net"

## Using strsplit
sapply(phrase, 
       function(x) strsplit(x, ":|\\?", fixed=FALSE)[[1]][2], 
       USE.NAMES=FALSE)
# [1] "fwwrp-3492801490@yahoo.com"     "somefunk.y-address@Sqmpalm.net"
```

I prefer the brevity of the `gsub` approach.

Comment: Thanks Anado , I'll go over your answers as well. I like your implementation of having the gibberish before the semicolon.